# Securing old armored cable with fraying conductor insulation

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am trying to replace my overhead porch light and found two runs of MC 2-wire (no ground), one per unit, going to one bulb respectively. This worked fine and I was able to find a replacement light fixture.

The challenge is the condition of the MC cable - as you can imagine, it's very old and the wire insulation is fraying. I would like to make this the last time I have to touch it and disturb it.

I purchased a junction box, put two holes in it for the MC cable, attached clamps, and started to shore up the wires with heat shrink.

When it comes time to install the new fixture, I'll run some NM conduit from the side of the junction box to an appropriate outlet box, and hang the fixture off of that. The junction box will be accessible via a hole in the cladding that I'll cut, so it will be up to code.

Is this an appropriate way to handle this fraying cable?

Pictures included. I got rid of the original mounting plate shown in the first pic.

[image: Current state (there is a cover on it as well)]
[image: Original state]
[!Original state, area view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWShc.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWShc.jpg)
[image: Original state, close up]

Comment: Any info on the condition of the cable into and past the wood? If accessible, it would probably make sense to replace the run.  There are a number of plastic and metal "weatherproof" boxes in different shapes and sizes; looks like your fixture might be wide enough to cover such a box from direct view from below. According to code, any junction box needs to be accessible, so I think no cladding on top, unless perhaps there was a removable access panel/hatch right over the junction box. Perhaps a junction box deep enough to stick out below the cladding surface?

Comment: Your metal cables are more likely type "AC" than "MC". It is also very possible that they provide a grounding path, and if so that should be preserved. That would mean using proper clamps rated for use with AC cable, a metal box, and using a ground wire connected to the box for any NM extensions to that circuit. Using plastic boxes with ad hoc holes and hardware is not the way to go, your local hardware store no doubt has lots of gear specifically designed to work with metallic flexible cables.

Comment: Is there a reason you're wanting to use plastic boxes with metal sheathed cable?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I’m open to suggestions

Comment: Don't use _green_ heat shrink! Any future maintainer will wonder why in the world you've got a hot and ground and wonder where the neutral went. As I was reading your question, I kept glancing at the first picture wondering _exactly_ that...

Comment: @Jeremy -- generally speaking, metal sheathed cables and metal conduits are used with metal boxes and metal boxes *only*